# Store an image in memory or in a browser cache with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Now in my rails app i have stored one image from url,that stored in my system **tmp** folder. But the problem is i am using **heroku** to running this rails app, so how will be the storing process when running with heroku?

```
def mail
@image = https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=5&choe=UTF-8
path_image = "/tmp/img.png"
open(@image) do |chart|
 File.open(path_image, 'wb') {|f| f.write chart.read }
end
welcome(path_image)
end
```

Thanks

Comment: You can save your files on s3 or some similar service. rdoc: http://rdoc.info/gems/s3/frames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [Heroku's Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem), you can store *temporary* files in the `#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/` (Rails 2) or `Rails.root.join('tmp')` (Rails 3) directories.

Comment: In rails 3that will be Rails.root